# Query sharepoint list anonymously

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

Hi do i access a sharepoint list with anonymous authentication? I am trying to read a sharepoint list with javascript and it only works if I have logged in with an admin user but if I have not logged in I get the "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." error message.
 My code is as below

```
var siteUrl = "http://site/subsite";

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current;
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Subscriptions');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\'EMail\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>searchText</Value></Contains></Where></Query></view>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

I believe the site is set to allow anonymous authentication. The subsite also. The list also allows anonymous user to view items. I am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: I've not had success with the CSOM and anonymous authentication for querying data - have you tried the same as a simple REST API call? A "contains" filter can be achieved via the ODATA 'substringof' operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection7

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when trying to caml query my list anonymously via JSOM. Any luck on your end?

Answer (score 0):

By default the site is not set to allow anonymous authentication. You have to allow anonymous authentication explicitly from IIS.

Please check if you are able to browse that site with the anonymous user.

Comment: I can browse the site anonymously but, when I query a the "Subscriptions" list with javascript I get the above mentioned error

Comment: did you also configured (unchecked) "Require Use Remote Permissions" setting in CA? This may be blocking your CSOM. http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-a-sharepoint-site-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

By default getitems method of list is blocked on SharePoint. You will have to open it using power shell script.

https://sharepointinaction.wordpress.com/tag/the-method-getitems-of-the-type-list-is-blocked-by-the-administrator-on-the-server/